# Bluetooth Network access point problems

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, pi-zero-w, dhcp

Hi we have two Pis (A Pi3 acting as a server/gateway and a Pi0W acting as the client) and we are trying to get them to communicate. They are connected via Bluetooth, and the Pi3 has a NAP server running, but the Pi0W cannot get an IP address from it. 
I guess the question is, how do I set up a Pi so that there is a DHCP *server* running on some interfaces (Namely, br0 and possibly bnep0) and a *client* on other interfaces (Namely, eth0 and wlan0). The Pi3 needs connection to the Internet.
I know it should be possible.

Interfaces on the Pi3:
lo
eth0
wlan0
br0
bnep0 (When BT connected)

On the Pi0W:
lo
wlan0
bnep0 (When BT connected)